# UWP UserControl with Canvas: how do you draw?

Tags: canvas, uwp, user-controls, uno-platform

For the Uno platform, based on UWP, I want to create a UserControl which contains a Canvas where I can draw something. I can't find any documentation or examples on what drawing events occur and how to use them.

I believe my XAML can be, minimally, like this:

```
<UserControl
  x:Class="UnoTest.Shared.Controls.ExpandableImage"
  ...
  <Canvas />
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind like this:

```
namespace UnoTest.Shared.Controls
{
  public sealed partial class ExpandableImage : UserControl
  {
    public ExpandableImage()
    {
      this.InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

And, surely, there must be some callbacks for drawing on the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Win2D CanvasControl](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/QuickStart.htm) if you want to draw arbitrary graphics in a UserControl.

[SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)  [Uno Platform](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.SkiaSharp) is also an option if you want to target the Uno Platform.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this needs to work on the Uno platform. From what I've read, Win2D only works for Windows devices. I'll check, to be sure.

Comment: What do you want to draw?

Comment: At this point, I'm mostly experimenting, to find some of the limitatons of Uno. I want to create a simplified Android 9-patch. So I will load an image into a bitmap, take some pieces of that, put them on the canvas and do some fill-in.

Comment: I think I have correctly incorporated SkiaSharp into my uno project. It's taking me some time to write code - I need to figure out how to create a custom control for uno.

Comment: Ok, this level of implementation works on, at least UWP. Haven't got far enough to test on other heads.

Answer (score 0):

Jerome Laban talked about how to use SkiaSharp on the Uno Platform in a twitch livestream yesterday. Maybe that's interesting for you: https://www.twitch.tv/videos/880058411?t=0h36m27s

I don't know how long the video will stay on twitch, but I think they'll upload the stream to youtube in the next days. Here is the link to the youtube playlist regarding the twitch streams: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl_OlDcUya9pRqt9A0vpyi89Vl-uq3nSb

Hopefully the video will appear there in some days.

Comment: Linked answers should probably not be used, because you cannot rely that it'll remain there for a long while. If possible, provide the answer yourself, and use the link as a helpful source.